# How to create a text file in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm going to store an activation code, so I'm looking for a simple way to store a single line text file. How to create a single (or multiline, if I use `#13#10` line feeding) text file in Inno Setup ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InnoSetup's [Pascal Scripting](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) has a function called SaveStringToFile which should do what you need.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a link to the function [SaveStringToFile](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_savestringtofile).

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_savestringtofile